# Quartz cron expression to run job at every 14 minutes from now

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to run a job at every 14 minutes form now.

For example if I schedule a job at 11:04 am, using `0 0/14 * * * ?` cron expression.
then expected fire time suppose to be 11:18,11:32,11:46 and so on .
but it will fire at 11:00,11:14:11,28:11:42,11:56,12:00 which is not expected.
and why it fired at 12:00 o'clock after 11:56, there is diff of only 4 min.

- How can I achieve what I want using cron expression?
- Can any one explain me this behaviour of quartz cron?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 0/14 give you fire time at 00, 14, 28, 42, 56 and again at 00 minutes of every hour. So last interval will be not 14 but 4 minutes. Thats how cron works. You can get equals interval in minutes only for cases when remainder of the division 60 by your interval is zero.

Answer (score 8):

your cron expression should look like

```
0 0/14 * 1/1 * ? *
```

A great website to create your cron expression when you are in doubt : http://www.cronmaker.com/

it will help you build your cron expression and show you the next firing date times of your cron.

For More Reference : http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Answer (score 1):

You get it wrong. `0/14` means it will fire each hour starting from `0` after `14min`. That's why it is firing at `12.00`

Comment: is cron expression doesn't care of current time? if i ask to start a job at every 14 min at 11:02 then it should fire first job at 11:16 instead of 11:14.

Comment: @Vipul follow this link to understand the behavior of cron. http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Answer (score 1):

"0 0/14 * * * ?" means the next fire time from the beginning of the clock for every 14 minutes interval, like what you said.

The 1st '0' means SECOND at 0 (or 12) at the clock; and same for the 2nd '0' which means the MINUTE at 0 (or 12) at the clock; '/14' means 14 minutes as the interval.

**So get the SECOND and MINUTE from current time** and concatenate them with the interval into a cron expression then fire it. Below is the example for Java:

```
public static String getCronExpressionFromNowWithSchedule(int minuteInterval) throws Exception {
    String cronExpression = "";
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
    int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    if (minuteInterval<=0) cronExpression = (second+1)+" * * * * ?";
    else cronExpression = (second+1)+" "+minute+"/"+minuteInterval+" * * * ?";

    System.out.println(cronExpression);
    return cronExpression;
}
```

The next fire time is at next second from current time for the Minute interval you passed into this method.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your `cron` expression to `0 0/14 * 1/1 * ? *`

Answer (score 0):

Use this cron expression.

`0 0/14 * *` * ?