# Cronjobs run always at o'clock but also on their input times

Tags: php, azure, cron

How can this cronjobs that I set on Azure to run every 22, 57 and 7 minutes run always at 00 minutes?

For example they run at 01:00, 02:00, 03:00 but also on their set times.

[image]

Comment: 0 */22 is minute zero every 22nd hour. you have mixed minutes and hours

Comment: He has 6 elements in his cronjob. AFAIK crontab can't do seconds though, so I don't know what that `0` is...

Comment: @rtfm Per the Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs), the first element is `{second}`.

Comment: so they messed with a 50 year old program parameters, would of been smarter to at least renamed it

Comment: Some people need to run stuff every 22 seconds. Since this is the cloud you have to give people the tool to accomplish that without the 50-year old `*/1 * * * *  sleep 38 && ./do_it` approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz cron expression to run job at every 14 minutes from now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417600/quartz-cron-expression-to-run-job-at-every-14-minutes-from-now)